# Arrange Pivot Columns Using Record Macro

Tags: excel, macros, record, vba

I'm a macro noob, however I have quite a bit of experience recording macros and manipulating code to make adjustments. Today I have an issue I need to solve. I am trying to record a macro to reorganize the order of the columns within a pivot. I have tried recording a macro while I move the values around in the PivotTable Fields form, as well as clicking the Value field in the PivotTable Fields section and selecting "Move to End". Both are not working and I'm getting left with an error, "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument. Below is the code from the recording for reference.

**How can I properly reorganize the columns of a pivot using a macro or macro recording?**

Thanks,
Steve

---

```
Sub PivotColumnArrange()
'
' PivotColumnArrange Macro
' Arranges Pivot Columns In Proper Order
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of AverageCPC"), "Sum of AverageCPC", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of AveragePos."), "Sum of AveragePos.", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of Conversions"), "Sum of Conversions", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CPA "), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CPA "), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CVR "), "Sum of CVR ", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CTR"), "Sum of CTR", xlSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues. It looks like you are referring to the Value field names, e.g., "Sum of CPA " when you should be referring to "CPA". Also, your code creates to identically named fields, i.e., "Sum of CPA " is used twice.

Try changing this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CPA "), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of CPA "), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum
```

to this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("CPA"), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("CPA"), "Sum of CPA2 ", xlSum
```

I'm guessing at the source field name ("CPA") and perhaps the second one is actually meant to be another operation, like Average (or was just an accident).

Comment: not better to first `Dim PvtTbl as PivotTable` , then `Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")`, and then the rest is clear , like `PvtTbl.AddDataField PvtTbl.PivotFields("CPA"), "Sum of CPA ", xlSum`